# PHP imagecopymerge Cannot merge jpg and png into a single new image

Tags: php, gd

I have tried many stackoverflow answers but cannot get solution what i want, my code cannot merge properly both images into a new image.

[image]

and I don't want to use ImageMagic Lib

```
$height = 527;
$width = 1350;

$back_img = 'http://localhost/testphoto/Mtw2xHqGGd5FkDF2eQ4Z.png';
$front_img = 'http://localhost/testphoto/BHp7zWb8MB18sr8mzY1v________________.png';


$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($back_img));
$frame = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($front_img));


$image = imagecreatefrompng($back_img);
$frame = imagecreatefrompng($front_img);

imagecopymerge($frame, $image, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, $height, $width);


imagepng($image, 'image.png');
```

Comment: See the top-ranked comment here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php#92787

Comment: thanks but not working,
I copied code and run
but bellow code only 'BHp7zWb8MB18sr8mzY1v________________.png' in result of image  
imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
 // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
 imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);


bellow code only 'Mtw2xHqGGd5FkDF2eQ4Z.png' in result of image  

imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);
 // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
 imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that. I'd much rather keep the images unaltered, and apply a mask over them with CSS or SVG.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Comment: Thanks @GaryHayes,  Digital Chris solved by problem, but i need a merged final image to preview for print.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use imagecopy() function, not imagecopymerge().

Example:

```
imagecopy($FirstImage, $NewImage,$centerXofNewImageInTheFirstImage,$centerYofNewImageInTheFirstImage,$xStartofNewImage,$yStartofNewImage,$xENDofNewImage,$yENDofNewImage);
```